# Merge json files using jq (one input object per file -> one larger output object, not a list)

Tags: json, jq

I am merging two json files using "jq -s . file1 file2", but I want them to get merged without comma separation. Also it shouldn't start with []

**file 1:**

```
{
  "node1": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node2": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

**file 2:**

```
{
  "node3": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node4": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

**Output using jq -s . file 1 file 2**

```
[
    {
      "node1": {
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "OS": "linux"
      },
      "node2": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "node3": {
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "OS": "linux"
      },
      "node4": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux"
      }
    }
]
```

**Required output:**

```
{
  "node1": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node2": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
    "node3": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node4": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me finding solution to this, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option slong the lines of your attempt:

```
jq -s add file1 file2
```

Another:

```
   jq -n 'input+input' file1 file2
```